# User session is still valid after a database refresh

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum

On a Laravel API with authentication using [Laravel Sanctum in SPA mode](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authentication) after a database refresh the session is still valid.

After running `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` the previously logged-in user is not disconnected and can request the API with 200 status code, a valid response body and the `Set-Cookie` in the response's headers.

Does anyone have ever encountered this issue before?

Comment: Thats probably because the session is still valid

Comment: @Donkarnash Yeah I thought about it but how can the session be still valid if my user doesn't anymore exist in my database? How can Laravel rebuild a Session Token and an XSRF-Token on each request?

Comment: Laravel Sanctum uses Laravel's built-in session authentication. You are probably using the file session driver, or something else which is not the database. So those sessions still exist even if you refresh the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I found the solution just before your comment. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just got the answer from a friend of mine, the point is that with the default session driver in Laravel, `file`, sessions aren't deleted when refreshing the database.

I just ran `rm -rf storage/framework/sessions/*` and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: You can also change the APP_KEY with `php artisan key:generate`, after a database refresh. It will invalidate all sessions regardless of the driver. (Keep in mind that it shouldn't be used in production to invalidate session, it might breaks [things](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption).)